# Git problems - how to set up a NAS with a repo for a website

Tags: git

I've asked this before in a variation, but know I understand more and I need some help.

Can someone PLEASE outline the process to adding a git server and then linking to it.

For example.  I have a synology NAS running a git server  its LAN ip is 192.168.1.135
I have a PC with LAN IP of 192.168.1.103..  I've tried so many variations I'm a bit lost.  But, assumng I have a website I want to push upto my NAS into the folder volume1/git/site. While the true path to the site folder is volume1/web/site.

I also have the folder site on my PC.  What I want is to push my change out from my local PC to my NAS git server.  SO that when I update the files locally, they can be pushed to the NAS(which acts as a webserver)  In order to achieve this, how do I set up the remotes and initialize the repositories, I've tried initializing one as bare and the other as working as in directory/.git as well as directory.git, however whenever I add the remote with

```
remote add origin NASuser@NASIP:volume1/git/site
```

or even

```
remote add origin NASuser@NASIP:volume1/git/site.git
```

from the local box

I've even tried to, from the NAS use

```
remote add origin PCuser@PCIP:path/to/git/site or path/to/site.git
```

I'm missing something for sure, I had it working in the past, I can do commits, but any fetch/push/pull fails giving the error:

```
Could not read from remote repository - Please make sure you have correct access rights
```

and

i did perform add . or go thro and add every file to track, my only issue is and my real question is, if I have a local copy of a site, and I want to push it to a remote server and then be able to push updates to that server, and have other people push updates to that server, which repos do i init as bare? local or the NAS repo that is where the git server is located.  And secondly if those aren't an option, could I set the repo and files up on the nas, and then add them to be tracked by git from there?  In that case how would I go about adding remotes? origin is the "origin" of where the base files come from, master I'm not sure the diff between origin and master, and once I can get this fixed I do know how to use branches and checkouts.  So any help would be much appreciated..

Basically,  What are my options? I have a website, and a NAS git server to push the site content to and publish it to the web, since my NAS has a built in webserver.  My issue is, on which machine do I use a bare repo and how do I set up remotes so that I wont get the warning regarding invalid permissions.

It's late and my typing is poor, please point out any mistakes and I will correct the promptly.  Please help me with this issue, upon fixing it I will have smooth sailing,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out how to do it.  Poorly worded question.  The answers lie in specific configuration options that will not apply to NAS and setups other than my own.  My apologies, if you find yourself facing the same issue.  Find documentation about git servers and permissions.  It can be complicted, and git isn't for beginners which I was when I asked this question.  By the time you master git you should be able to take care of this.  But the answer to the question is this:  you can have a git server which hosts the repos, bitbucket works, a self hosted works, anything really.  You can put git say on your production machine and on your home and dev machines.  After making production, testing, and other brances.  You can clone the files from live site to git server then to your dev machine.  You can work on the site, and push to the git server to a testing or dev branch.  After working the kinks out you can eventually pull the changes up to the production server and branch after fixing up the branches.  There are many other ways to set permissions and do this and better way to deploy that just pulling into production.  But that is the easiest as long as you are careful and know what to not do.